# Stylus Middleware not compiling CSS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, stylus

Can you please help me with **Stylus Middleware**. I cannot make him to compile css file.

Here is my app.js code:

```
// Module dependencies
var express = require('express');
var stylus = require('stylus');
var nib = require('nib');
var logger = require('morgan');

// Compile function - check this function online
function compile(str, path){
return stylus(str)
.set('compress', true)
.use(nib())
}

// Stylus Middleware (functions that handles request)
app.use(logger('dev')); //replaces your app.use(express.logger());
app.use(stylus.middleware({ 
src: __dirname + '/stylus',
dest: __dirname + '/public',
compile: compile
}))
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public/static'));
```

Structure of my root folder is as following:

> userApp
>
> > app.js
> >
> > stylus
> >
> > > styles.styl
> >
> > public
> >
> > > css

I have tried all that was posted previously but with no luck. I am a bit stuck and going in circles with this so if you have any advice it would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Probably the problem is that the src folder need to have the same folder structure with dest folder or vice versa [It's a common mistake]. I mean if you set th src to `__dirname + '/stylus'` and dest to `__dirname + '/public'` and you have a folder called css in /stylus and then the style [ i.e. `./stylus/css/style1.styl` then the dest needs to be `./public/css/style.css`. I think I've struggled with this myself. Check my structure and my code in app.js.

app.js

```
function compile(str, path) {
  return stylus(str)
    .set('filename', path)
    .use(nib())
    .set('compress', true)
    .import('nib');
}

app.use(stylus.middleware({
  src: __dirname + '/resources',
  dest: __dirname + '/public',
  debug: true,
  force: true
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

[image]

Comment: I have made it! Tnx radubogdan and Peter Lyons, I have used both of your suggestions.

Comment: Hehe. I'm glad :) You can upvote both answers then ;)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is because you have omitted the `filename` setting your compile is failing if you have any `@import` or `@require` statements where the path can't be properly resolved. Try this:

```
// Compile function - check this function online
function compile(str, path){
  return stylus(str)
  .set('filename', path)
  .set('compress', true)
  .use(nib());
}
```